# In Spark, do we have a guarantee that data in the same partition comes from the same file

Tags: apache-spark

To simplify my usecase let's suppose that I have multiple huge files that I load with spark with the following code :

```
val df = spark.read.textFile(files: _*)
              .withColumn("partition_id", spark_partition_id())
              .withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())
```

This gives a spark dataframe like:

```
____________________________________________
|value        |partition_id|input_file_name|
|some line    |0           |file1          |
|some line    |0           |file1          |
|some line    |1           |file1          |
|some line    |1           |file1          |
|some line    |2           |file2          |
|some line    |2           |file2          |
```

As you know a single file can be spread over multiple spark partitions ( *1* input_file_name -> *n* partition_id)

My question is: Do we have a guarantee that for a single partition, the input_file_name is always the same?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not convinced the question makes sense. Files and blocks are on persistent storage, partitions are in memory or spilled onto disks having been read or being read and in process of being processed. What are you concerned about in reality?

Answer (score 1):

I did many tests, and the answer is No, if you have small files, one partition may contain many lines coming from multiple files